# Upper and lower bound for fraction function : $ \sum_{n=0}^{N-1}(-1)^n\binom{N-1}{n}\frac{1}{(n+1)*cx} $

Tags: upper-lower-bounds

Let $c$ and $N$ be two positive  real number with $c>0$, and $x$ very high number.
The number $c$ have two cases $c<1$ and $c\geq 1$.

if ther is any upper bound and lower bound for the following expression
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}(-1)^n\binom{N-1}{n}\frac{1}{(n+1)*cx} 
$$ 
for the two case.

Can we upper bound $$
\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}(-1)^n\binom{N-1}{n}\frac{1}{(n+1)*cx} 
$$  by $$
\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}(-1)^n\binom{N-1}{n}\frac{1}{n+cx} 
$$
or can we do 
\begin{align}
ncx+cx\geq& n+cx\\
\frac{1}{ncx+cx}\leq& \frac{1}{n+cx}
\end{align}

Comment: Why not just factor the $1/cx$ out of the sum?

Comment: if we can write upper bound with $$
\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}(-1)^n\binom{N-1}{n}\frac{1}{n+cx} $$ is perfect7

Comment: $n+cx\ne(n+1)cx$, which one do you mean?

Comment: ok i hop if we can upper bound $$
\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}(-1)^n\binom{N-1}{n}\frac{1}{(n+1)*cx} 
$$  by $$
\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}(-1)^n\binom{N-1}{n}\frac{1}{n+cx} 
$$

Comment: This is not clear. If that is your question, please post it in the question.

Comment: You cannot bound it like that so easily, since there is a $(-1)^n$ term in the sum.

Comment: OK so there is any solution ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76707/discussion-between-mokhtar-and-simply-beautiful-art).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that

$$\frac1{n+y}=\int_0^1x^{n+y-1}{\rm~d}x$$

and that

$$\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}\binom{N-1}n(-1)^nx^{n+y-1}=x^{y-1}(1-x)^{N-1}$$

which gives

$${\rm B}(y,N)=\int_0^1x^{y-1}(1-x)^{N-1}{\rm~d}x$$

which is the [beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function). Assuming $y$ is a natural number, this gives us

> $$\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}\binom{N-1}n\frac{(-1)^n}{n+y}=\frac{(y-1)!(N-1)!}{(y+N-1)!}$$

which reduces the problem to bounding the factorials, which can be done via things such as Stirling approximations.

And for the other sum,

$$\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}\binom{N-1}n\frac{(-1)^n}{(n+1)cx}=\frac1{Ncx}$$

which may be derived from the above.

Comment: ok if there is any possibility that the term $\frac{1}{(cx)^N}$  appear in the upper  bound

Comment: what if we upper bound $$
\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}(-1)^n\binom{N-1}{n}\frac{1}{(n+1)*cx} 
$$ by $$
\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}\binom{N-1}{n}\frac{1}{(n+1)*cx} 
$$ since we have $cx$ is large so $1/((n+1)*cx)$ will be close to zero $-1/((n+1)*cx)$ also

Comment: I see no reason for $1/(cx)^N$ to appear in relation to the sums.

Comment: To the second comment, sure, that would be a valid bound, though I still see no point in the $cx$ in the denominator.

Comment: ok sure i will try to do another think thank you so much